# How to use TFBertModel's hidden states as part of custom Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers

I want to use hidden_states of bert as an input for the next layer and build it using keras.Model. But bert returns only last layer and pooler output.

Here's the code that I've tried:

```
def _def_input():
    input_ids = Input(batch_shape=(None, 256), name='input_ids', dtype='int32')
    input_type_ids = Input(batch_shape=(None, 256), name='input_type_ids', dtype='int32')
    attention_mask = Input(batch_shape=(None, 256), name='attention_mask', dtype='int32')

    return [input_ids, input_type_ids, attention_mask]

config = BertConfig.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased", output_hidden_states=True)
model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased", config=config)
inputs = _def_input()

out = model({'input_ids': inputs[0],
                 'token_type_ids': inputs[1],
                 'attention_mask': inputs[2]})
print(f'Out len: {len(out)}')
print(f'Out: {out}')
print(model.config)
```

And here's the output:

```
Out len: 2
Out: (<tf.Tensor 'tf_bert_model_10/Identity:0' shape=(None, 256, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'tf_bert_model_10/Identity_1:0' shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>)
BertConfig {
  "architectures": [
    "BertForMaskedLM"
  ],
  "attention_probs_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "directionality": "bidi",
  "gradient_checkpointing": false,
  "hidden_act": "gelu",
  "hidden_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "hidden_size": 768,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "intermediate_size": 3072,
  "layer_norm_eps": 1e-12,
  "max_position_embeddings": 512,
  "model_type": "bert",
  "num_attention_heads": 12,
  "num_hidden_layers": 12,
  "output_hidden_states": true,
  "pad_token_id": 0,
  "pooler_fc_size": 768,
  "pooler_num_attention_heads": 12,
  "pooler_num_fc_layers": 3,
  "pooler_size_per_head": 128,
  "pooler_type": "first_token_transform",
  "type_vocab_size": 2,
  "vocab_size": 119547
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of transformers you used? I met the same issue and downgrading transformers to 2.7.0 solved my case, as suggested in this link: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/6029